# How to edit column in Sql Server table?

Tags: sql-server

How can I edit one of  columns in a SQL server table ?
I want to change the type of one of columns from  n var char (50) to n var char (100). When I do it, this error appears :
**saving changes is not permitted.**
how can I do it?

Comment: Just increasing the length of a column should be allowed without having to re-create the table. Is that definitely the *only* thing you changed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, you're right. but I don't know why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Sql Server Management Studio`

Tools-> Options -> Designers -> Uncheck Prevent saving changes that requires  table re-creation.

["Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created" negative effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802429/prevent-saving-changes-that-require-the-table-to-be-re-created-negative-effect)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956176