# SQL server: can't save/change table design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make changes to an existing table and am getting this error when i try to save :

> Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created. You have either made changes to a table that can't be re-created or enabled the option Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created.

I only have one data entry in the database - would deleting this solve the problem or do i have to re-create the tables as the error suggests? (This is on SQL-Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Try the suggestion offered in the last part of the message: disable the option _Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created_. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802429/prevent-saving-changes-that-require-the-table-to-be-re-created-negative-effect). And in the future please include the error message in your question. An image stored elsewhere may not be available when others look at the question in the future.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following actions might require a table to be re-created:

1. Adding a new column to the middle of the table
2. Dropping a column
3. Changing column nullability
4. Changing the order of the columns
5. Changing the data type of a column

To change this option, on the Tools menu, click Options, expand Designers, and then click Table and Database Designers. Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created check box.

[refer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx)

Answer (score 27):

you need to change settings to save the changes

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
2. On the Tools menu, click Options.
3. In the navigation pane of the Options window, click Designers.
4. Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation check box, and then click OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Goto -> Tools -> Options->Designers-> Warn on null primary keys and 
Warn about tables affected
```

uncheck and try again