# Can't show database table in object explorer when created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created table, but when I set columns, data types and save it, table not seen in left object explorer. I want to open the table and enter data in it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on your database node or database-Tables node and click Refresh in context menu

Comment: ok thanks, can you tell me why i cant set data type datetime for column name birthday. 
if i set datetime data type and gonna to save table i got warning box with txt:"Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you  made require the following to be dropped an re=created."...
Can i set another data type nchar or something else.

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802429/prevent-saving-changes-that-require-the-table-to-be-re-created-negative-effect