# “Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created” Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I was modifying a column in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio (SSMS) and got the  error:

> The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped
>   and re-created

I'm testing and so I don't have any problem with dropping and re-creating new tables. Where is the option to disable this error?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802429/prevent-saving-changes-that-require-the-table-to-be-re-created-negative-effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server 'Saving changes is not permitted' error ► Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810425/sql-server-saving-changes-is-not-permitted-error-prevent-saving-changes-that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tools --> Options --> Designers --> Table and Database Designers**

In here you will find the following checked option:

> Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation

Just uncheck it!

Answer (score 0):

[Sql Server Prevent Saving Error in Server 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU3Sz.png)To change the Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation option, follow these steps:

Open **SQL Server** Management Studio.

On the Tools menu, click **Options**.

In the navigation pane of the Options window, click **Designers**.

**Select** or **clear** the **Prevent** saving changes that require the table re-creation check box, and then click **OK**.