# Update the size of a column in SQL Server without affecting statistics

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm confused and the truth is I don't know what else to do, I have a database column that has a datatype `numeric(8, 4)` and I need to change it to `numeric(12, 2)`.

When I want to update it, it tells me a message that the change cannot be applied, because it has associated statistics indexes and it shows me a referenced text to which statistics it would affect.

My question is: how can I update the column without affecting the statistics or what actions should I take to proceed to update the column from the database?

SQL Server 2008

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11802429/61305 ... of course you should not take this change lightly if your table is large, and should probably never make a change to your table by pointy-clicky UI things, but there's not much you can do to save the statistics. Any index or statistic that would be _useful_ on that column, you'd want to rebuild even if there was a way to avoid it.

Comment: Drop and recreate the statistics. Although if it's part of an index you probably have to drop that too

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, I had to delete the index, apply the change, and then recreate it, I had no other option